# ngAnimate Flip Animation

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-animate

I spent the last 5 hours trying to get this animation to work with no luck. I wanted to create a cool animation whenver the user click on a button, the idea is to display a list of ul elements in a flip animation, pretty much like what http://lab.hakim.se/scroll-effects/mobile.html is doing (if you selected flip from the gear icon and changed chrome device mode to a mobile device).

Im using ngAnimate along with Angular and Ionic, I created the snippet here http://play.ionic.io/app/4ae65754fc64 (try to click the Add to Cart button). I want to display each li item as if they are flip and cascading whenever they are displayed. For some reason all the animation classed are ignored.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle like your link where at least the items are added and displayed to the screen with no animations so that people can focus on your animations issues. Your link is unusable as is.

Comment: @floribon yup you just need to click the Add to Cart button and the list would show up

Comment: My bad! I thought you wanted to animate upcoming items and not the number tiles, I'm sorry please ignore my comment.

Comment: you want to display 1,2,3,4,5 in flip animation right?

Comment: @PareshGami yup exactly, with a delay for each of several milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I achieved what you were wanting to achieve. I provided you two demos below.

But first of all the ng-animate directive is not supported anymore in AngularJS >= 1.2. And for ng-show based animations you have to use the ng-hide-add, ng-hide-remove CSS classes not the CSS classes described in the ngRepeat documentation.

The ionic demo (first link below) is basicly just a mockup of your code and is not perfect by any means.

The codepen demo is a bit more modified example and generic example. I used `<ion-list>` and `<ion-item>` instead of `<ul>` and `<li>`.

Hopefully this gets you in the right direction when implementing your final solution.

**Ionic demo**: http://play.ionic.io/app/3c0e90238fe8

**Codepen demo (more generic)**: http://codepen.io/thepio/pen/KMPeZo